# GitHub image file on md not showing on mobile

Tags: github, markdown

I uploaded an image on .md file. I did drag & drop.
And this is the generated raw code.

`![image](https://github.com/sdhong0609/tech-interview-study/assets/78577085/537aa20a-e099-4afb-b225-b3d03b981007)`

The problem is that I can see image well on my laptop, but I can't see image on my phone, like GitHub mobile app and mobile browser.
It shows like this on my phone.

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DZSz.jpg)

What should I do to fix this?

I hope the phone shows my images on mobile.

Comment: Could be because of an unsupported image format. Please add more detail to the question else it will just be guessworks.